# How do server nodes distribute content to all CDN nodes in a quick manner?

Tags: cdn

Let’s say we have a main server that handles user uploaded content.

The main server receives the file and sends it to a CDN. How does the CDN distribute that new file to all nodes around the world so quickly? Wouldn’t it take minutes to send the content to each node individually?

Comment: "Wouldn’t it take minutes to send the content to each node individually"
What assumptions is this statement based on? Why do you consider it a fact? What files are we talking about? it takes seconds, depending on route for few migs, and it takes hours if we are talking about about 600GB zip files.

Comment: Also, you don't usually upload to CDN (if we are talking about something like cloudflare). Your content is simply on your server, and when serving to a new user, since the user connects to your website through Cloudflare, the CDN gets the ressource from you and cache it while serving it to the user. That way next user from same region, will be served from the cached content. (this is a very simplistic model, and it is not exactly what CF does, but it gives you an idea)

Comment: @user206904 Let’s say it’s a 200 mb file. It would have to go through to each CDN node so all users across the world can access it from their local node. What happens during the transfer period? How do users get the content?

Comment: No, it does not has to go everywhere. As I said, on request, while serving, the node keeps a copy (first connection), if the node already has a copy it is serves it directly without connecting to your main server.  if your site is never visited by Chinese people, your files won't be cached on the nodes serving china. You are really not giving any details. Each company can (and DOES) implement things the way they want, no unique formula. Also, a service like DG and CF won't cache your 200MB files, they mainly cache CSS,JS,images, etc

Comment: I am actually surprised this question is still not closed due to "lacking clarification". You don't specify any details so that we can give an answer

Comment: Ok, here's more details. I don't want to be using Cloudflare. I want to make my own CDN for a file host. The CDN caches the files on each node globally so that users from every region of the world have a fast connection and load times.

Comment: do all servers(/nodes) to  have all files? (all nodes are identical, but just you upload content to 1 (main) server?)

Comment: Yes, theoretically they do. That's part of my question. How does the main server transfer the content to all the nodes so quickly so that they can serve local visitors? What do local visitors see when their local CDN node does not yet have the content from the main server?

Comment: That is not CDN, in the usual sense in the industry (caching most accessed/most recent files). You are doing a distributed service, and you will probably need a load balancer or something and/or some nice nice advanced DNS service to handle the incoming requests and route them to their closest node. I will try to write an answer later when I have some more time.

Comment: I have modified your question to actually make sense and ask about what you want. Example of modifications "How does the CDN distribute...?", to me this question does not make any sense, the N in CDN is for Network, your asking "how does the network distribute", a network does not distribute on its own! It is the end terminals that do send and distribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Part 1:  Replication (distribution among nodes)

#### The problem: You have multiple servers, one "main" and other are "replicas"/"slaves", how to avoid manually uploading content to each server ?

##### **case 1**: if your content is static, html/js or other files (without DB):

You have you webserver (nginx or apache or whatever) pointing to some location on the server, right?

We will use 2 tools, rsync and cron scheduler.
Rsync allows you to sync a directory between 2 servers, so if folder in server A(source) gets modified, these modifications will be copied on a target server B.
Example of sync command:

```
rsync -rtu --delete /var/my/source/web/server root@x.x.x.x:/var/my/destin/web/server
```

Where `x.x.x.x` is the target machine IP.

You can read the manual for rsync or any tutorial to figure out more.

Now this command will do the sync only once, so you need to run it everytime there is a modification on main server, ofc we will not do that manually. So you can add this command in crontab. To do this:

```
crontab -e
```

Then just enter the frequency (each hour? each minute? each week) and the command:
Example to run a command each ten minutes:

```
*/10 * * * * rsync....
```

Again, it is up to you to read more on cron and set the frequency as you wish.

##### **case 2. if you need to replicate DB:**

Just do the same for web server to replicate files and depending on your DB engine, you will have to do a DB replication. Here are some examples:

https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-set-up-database-replication-with-mariadb/
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65351/sync-two-mysql-databases-in-two-different-locations
It's up to you to figure this one out, or ask a separate question on DB replication.

On all servers, you web server should have the same config, and they should all have  have vhost for the same domain and same SSL certificate.

## Part 2:  Visitors' access:

This is where it gets trickier, now that you have all servers ready, how can visitors get redirected to different servers?

The easiest, if you want them to be redirected randomly, you can use what is known as "round robin DNS"

Add multiple A name records for same domain, but each record will have a different IP. Users will *usually* get directed to their closest node depending on the route, but they may also get redirected to a node that is a bit far from them, it depends on routes and various network factors.

A bit more advanced method, you can use a (paid) load-balancing solution with some geo feature/closest node policy, which will simplify things (but this will be a bit like cheating), example: scaleway's load balancing service.

Or maybe if you want to do it on your own: use an advanced (paid) geo DNS service

> GeoDNS takes the geographical location from where a query is coming
> from and answers that query depending on what the owners of that
> domain have preset for that specific user's location.
> -constellix
> So as the domain owner, you define which region get redirected to which of your servers following a policy of (GeoProximity - Location Based DNS)

https://constellix.com/news/everything-you-need-to-know-about-geodns
https://easydns.com/features/geo-dns/

#### conclusion:

This is obviously not an easy 1 hour task and not cheap to implement on your own. Always remember to experiment on cheap (temp) servers and NOT your productions servers.